# Using session in ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

I am a newbie in node and express. I want to use cookies / session to notify my ejs once my registration is successful. I dont know which one is a better option, please suggest. Also help me with their usage.

Below are snippets of my controller ( server-side js ) and register-user ( client side js ).

registerController.js

```
app.post('/register',urlencodedParser,function(req,res){
  session=req.session;
  Users(req.body).save(function(err,data){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(" back from ajax with data :::; " + data);
    req.session.user='sasdad';      
    res.status(200).send('User saved successfully');
  });
});
```

register-user.js

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: '/register',
  data: user,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    var resp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    console.log(resp);
    if(resp["status"]==200){
      console.log("status == 200");
      window.location.href = '/';
    }  
    return data;
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log("inside error");
  }
  });

   return false;
});
```

EJS

```
<form action="/testAction">
  <label for="username"> Username </label>
  <input type="text" for="username" name="username"/>
  <label for="password"> Password </label>
  <input type="password" for="password" name="password" />
  <button type="submit">Log In</button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your use case. Looks like you are doing ajax to post the form and redirecting users to another page if it's successful. In the controller, you are saving the user in the session object, which is done correctly.

If you are going to be redirecting to another page via ajax anyway, maybe you could just do a form post (no need for ajax)? So, your form action goes to `register`. In your controller, you could do `res.redirect('welcome page');`
Then, on your welcome page's route, you could check if the user exists in your session. You could then display messages accordingly on the welcome page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: PLease help me with a sample